# how to add element in the array which select by switch case

Tags: arrays, swift, switch-statement

I want to call the function and given a type to let different array append the data from API. I have print out the count but customerViewData still has 0 element and selectCustomerListViewData has 10 elements. It seems that selectCustomerListViewData = customerViewData didn't work as what I think. For this case how to add element in the correct array? I know that I can create 3 function to solve this issue.

```
class CustomerListViewData{
  var customer_id: String = ""
  var name: String = ""
  var image: String = ""
  var birthday: String = ""
  var age: String = ""
  var gender: String = ""
  var mobile: String = ""
  var identityNumber: String = ""
  var isSelected: Bool = false
  var isChanged: Bool = false
}
    func getCustomerViewData(type: String)->[CustomerListViewData]{
        var selectCustomerListViewData: [CustomerListViewData]
        var selectCustomerRawData: GetCustomerResponse?
        switch type {
            case "1":
                selectCustomerListViewData = customerViewData
                selectCustomerRawData = customerRawData
                break
            
            case "2":
                selectCustomerListViewData = searchCustomerViewData
                selectCustomerRawData = searchCustomerRawData
                break
            
            default:
                selectCustomerListViewData = notificationCustomerViewData
                selectCustomerRawData = notificationCustomerRawData
                break
      }
      if let customerList = selectCustomerRawData?.customerList{
        for each in customerList{
            let customer = CustomerListViewData(each.customer_id, each.name, each.image ?? "", each.birthday, calculateAge(birthday: each.birthday), each.gender, each.spikeStatus, each.mobile ?? "", each.identityNumber ?? "")
            selectCustomerListViewData.append(customer)
           }
       }
       print("\(customerViewData.count)")
       print("\(selectCustomerListViewData.count)")
       return selectCustomerListViewData
   }
```

Comment: It's not clear what your issue is since we have no idea what all these properties are that you are using and also the question is unclear. You say customerListViewData.count is 0 but you are not printing it but rather customerViewData.count and also what is customerListViewData since it is not part of the code you have posted. Clarify your question and possibly add some testdata so that we have something that is reproducible

Comment: Unrelated but this is Swift: No `break` statements in `switch` cases (except to exit the `default` case immediately)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Sorry, there is a typo.

Comment: selectCustomerListViewData gets it's data from selectCustomerRawData so it is in no way clear how it is relevant or a problem that customerViewData is empty. There is just to much information missing from this question.

Comment: I add a switch case and use "+= selectCustomerListViewData" to the actual array in my function end. It solve my issue!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that arrays are value types, not reference types. You need to append the data to the actual array you intend to add values to.

I would split your method into two methods:

```
func processResponse(ofType type: String) {
    switch type {
    case "1":
        customerViewData += extractList(from: customerRawData)
    case "2":
        searchCustomerViewData += extractList(from: searchCustomerRawData)
    default:
        notificationCustomerViewData += extractList(from: notificationCustomerRawData)
    }
}

func extractList(from response: GetCustomerResponse?) -> [CustomerListViewData] {
    guard let response = response else { return [] }
    return response.customerList.map { customer in
        return CustomerListViewData(customer.customer_id, customer.name, /* ... */)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I add a switch case and use "+=" to the actual array. Thanks bro.

Comment: I have another question. How to recognize array is  value type or reference type?